# Force windows 10 to default to a specific username on the login screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

My girlfriend and I share a "couch laptop". It's the laptop we use when we're watching tv or in the living room. We each have our own account on this windows 10 laptop.

If I use the laptop, then logout when I'm done, when she attempts to use it, the login screen will default to MY username. This wouldn't be a problem except she NEVER remembers to click her username before typing her password and it ends up being a very frustrating experience for both of us because she thinks she's forgotten her password and I have to get up from whatever I'm doing to help.

How can I make the login always default to her username? I've tried the instructions here and they seem to have no effect:
https://gist.github.com/dbirks/ec4416c9064a323b14f435ee934efd71

They do not work even once. After changing the registry values and restarting the login still defaults to me.

Comment: What exactly have you tried in the instructions? These registry keys would have to be set over and over, because every time you log in they will be changed.  Why not require a username AND password be typed in? Which, ironically is how you prevent the last user from being displayed. https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-make-windows-10-ask-for-user-name-and-password-during-log-on/

Comment: @Appleoddity I have tried the exact steps in the instructions. They don't work even once. I can change the keys right before I restart and the login will still default to me

Comment: I think your girl-friend should be able to recognize her or your name on the start-up screen. In user settings you can defined even full, long names.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't disagree, but that's not what's happening, and it doesn't appear that it's going to happen, so I'm looking for a solution. I don't think my girlfriend is the only person who sees a password input and starts typing their password without making sure they're typing it in the correct place. Autopilot is real and it happens to all of us in different contexts...

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. Both I and my girlfriend have an account on my Windows 10 PC, although in practice it's only me that ever uses it. Up until a couple of days ago, the login page would always default to my account, presumably because I was always the last user, but suddenly it's started always defaulting to hers, which means that every time I want to use my PC I have to click my name first. Perhaps this is because her name comes before mine alphabetically? I don't know what changed but it's very annoying since I use the PC all day every day and she almost never uses it.